# CNAME & MX Records clashes while hosting website on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, hosting, cname, mx-record

I have a domain `example.com`. This is NOT taken from Route53. I hosted my website on S3. Mapped S3 bucket to Cloudfront, and CF URL to `example.com` via CNAME. I, initially, had deleted the entry `example.com` from MX records because we cannot have 2 same keys. Later, I realized, I've stopped receiving mail on my mail server. Now, I'm trying to add the MX records, but couldn't because of duplicate keys.
How can I solve this problem of supporting both MX records and CNAME with the same key?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing a similar problem, I first deleted my CNAME associated with Cloudfront, then added MX records, and finally added CNAME with CF again. Not sure how, but both MX and CNAME were now being added successfully. LOL.

Update:-

CNAME takes priority over MX records. So if you have the same value in CNAME and MX records, you'll stop receiving emails. So, as a solution, I added `www` as a subdomain in my CNAME. I now route my users to `www.example.com`. If any user browser to `example.com` without `www` as subdomain, I forward them to `www.example.com`.